# Google AppEngine with Silverlight client using Google Login

Tags: silverlight, google-app-engine, google-apps, rich-internet-application

I'd like to use Google AppEngine with Silverlight client. I'm hoping to use the Google login authentication mechanism within the Silverlight client. Is this possible? Does anyone have any example sites where a RIA client used in conjunction with Google AppEngine security?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your users log in via a regular HTML page, then send them to the page with the silverlight client. Anything else would be encouraging users to enter their credentials into a third-party site, which is a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't believe that is true, meaning if you have an installed application Google has a login that allows you to enter username and pwd in your application.  I believe silverlight is closer to windows application.  Here is the login mechanism

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html